# How can I show that a function is non-decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have the following function:

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{x}{x+1},& \text{if }x\ge 0,\\ 0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I want to prove that it is right-continuous and non-decreasing.

1. To show it's right continuous, I had to show that 
   $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} F(x)=F(0). $$
   $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} F(x)= \frac{0}{1+0} = 0 \quad\mbox{ and }\quad F(0)=0.$$
   Since they are both equal, that proves the right continuity. (correct me if I'm wrong plz)
2. For non-decreasing, I know that I must show that $x\le y$ implies $F(x)\le F(y)$, but I don't know how to do that. I can't find anything online to help.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: You can take the derivative and show that the derivative is non-negative for x>=0.  Even simpler, you can rearrange the expression to 1- (1/(1+x)), so that should be obviously increasing as x increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of proving that a function is non-decreasing is to analyze the sign of its first derivative: roughly, given a function $f$, it will be non-decreasing if $f'(x)\ge 0$.

Since your function is continuous and has no singularity, you just need to compute $F'$ and observe that it can never be negative. If you do not now how to do it, ask for some hints.

---

EDIT: The first derivative of $F$ is given by
$$F'(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2},& x> 0,\\[5pt] 0,& x<0.\end{cases}$$

If you prefer not to use derivatives, you can also show that $F(x)\le F(y)$ if $x\le y$. First note that $\frac{x}{x+1}\ge 0$ for all $x\ge0$, so you just need to consider the case $0\le x\le y$. In that case, both $x+1$ and $y+1$ are positive, so:
$$\frac{x}{x+1}\le\frac{y}{y+1} \Leftrightarrow x(y+1)\le y(x+1) \Leftrightarrow x \le y.$$

Comment: thanks! The best way I can think of to show it's non-negative is to graph it, or to show that the limit as the derivative approaches infinity is 0 and the value of the derivative at x=0 is 1. Is this what you mean? Or is there a better way to show the function is non-negative?

Comment: Be careful. It is the first derivative what needs to be non-negative. Do you know how to compute it? Write it down and think about what values of $x$ (if there is any) would make it (the derivative!) negative.

Comment: So the derivative is `1/(x+1)^2` , this is obviously non-negative since it will always be a positive fraction. only way for it to be negative is if `x<-1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using derivatives, which is the easiest way, try the following direct approach:

$$0<x<y: \frac x{1+x}<\frac y{1+y}\iff x+xy<y+xy\iff x<y$$